# how to create an external javascript and an external css file for date picker and how to use it in eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, eclipse

I have a javascript and css style as below

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#startDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$('#startDate').datepicker();


});
</script> 
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true
});
});
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#endDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$('#endDate').datepicker();

});
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#followUpDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$('#followUpDate').datepicker();

});
</script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker th { background-color: #CCCCFF; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.search_textbx
{
background:url(calendar.jpg) right no-repeat;
background-color:white;
height:13px;
color:black;

}
</style>
```

Now my question is how to create an external javascript file and css file in eclipse so that i can use that in a jsp page especially in `input type = "text"`.

```
     <td style="padding-left:25px;">
<input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="search_textbx" size="15" readonly="readonly"/>
                          </td>
```

Now i need an external javascript file and css file and i want to use those files in the "input" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same way you are loading jquery and jquery-ui. Create a text file, save it as .css and as .js respectively, use a link and script tag to get them in your page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

ps: you don't have to use a new script tag for each function, you can just merge your three literal script into one `<script>` tag and one $(function(){});

for good measure, place css files in your head tag and script tags as low in the body tag as you can, unless you need to execute the script earlier.